# Check if string has all the letters of the alphabet

Tags: java, algorithm, logic

What would be the best logic to check all the letters in a given string.

If all the 26 letters are available in the provided string, I want to check that and perform so ops. eg. Pack my box with five dozen liquor jugs.

1. Would using a Hash be useful?
2. Or using a bit map? or any other way?

BTW my code would be in Java.

Comment: "pack my box with five doze liqor jugs"? Care to explain? :)

Comment: It is a [pangram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pangram), and one of the few short ones that actually makes sense.

Comment: Oh, and after you're done with the jugs, *Freight to me sixty dozen quart jars and twelve black pans.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not yet fully optimized:

```
public static void main(String... a) {
    String s = "Pack my box with five dozen liquor jugs.";
    int i=0;
    for(char c : s.toCharArray()) {
        int x = Character.toUpperCase(c);
        if (x >= 'A' && x <= 'Z') {
            i |= 1 << (x - 'A');
        }
    }
    if (i == (i | ((1 << (1 + 'Z' - 'A')) - 1))) {
        System.out.println("ok");
    }
}
```

Comment: So... use "int" instead of a BitSet. It has enough bits. In Java, "int" will always have 32 bits, unlike in C.

Comment: Wouldn't using `0x3FFFFFF` be faster?

Comment: The right side of the `|` contains no variables, so it would be calculated at compile time and stored as a constant.  (This assumes a compiler with an optimizer.)

Comment: @Blrfl, I meant faster `compilation`. heehee... :) true!

Comment: Actually, no need for (i | ...), you might as well use if (i == (1 << (1 + 'Z' - 'A')) - 1) - or Integer.bitCount(i) == 26.

Comment: You can get rid of the if (x >= 'A' && x <= 'Z') - but then you need to keep the (i | ...) as it is now.

Comment: Can you elaborate, bit operation that you are doing in details to provide some context?

Comment: Details: set each bit in the (32-bit-) integer where the given character is in the text. Bit 0 = A, bit 1 = B,... Then check if all bits that represent A - Z are set. If you don't understand bit operations then you need to read about it.

Answer (score 6):

Using a BitMap, I'm assuming you meant case insenstive.

Update: Solution by Thomas is more efficient, than the following. :) Use that one.

```
    //
    String test  = "abcdefeghjiklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

    BitSet alpha = new BitSet(26);
    for(char ch : test.toUpperCase().toCharArray())
        if(Character.isLetter(ch))
            alpha.set(ch - 65);

    System.out.println(alpha.cardinality() == 26);
```

Comment: Yes, but this is much more readable and maintainable.  And besides, mabye this operation doesn't need to be efficient.

Comment: Will grow the bit set for characters which aren't ASCII Latin.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. For example the following test string will incorrectly report "false": `abcdefeghjiklmnopqrstuvwxyzäöü`, and the following will incorrectly report "true": `abcdefeghjiklmnopqrstuvwäöü`. Please note there are 47444 (!) distinct "uppercase" characters for the Unicode codepoints 0 .. 0xffff.

Answer (score 3):

I'd go for a bitmap. If you increment a counter each time you set an entry in the bitmap to 1, you can early return as soon as you've seen all the letters.  I hope this is not for enforcing password requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Keep an `boolean` array of size 26. Each position of the array says whether a particular character is present or not (a is at 0, b is at 1, etc.). Initially all are set to false. Now do a single scan through the string character by character, setting the value for that character to true. At the end, check if all 26 indexes contain true.

Comment: OP requirements would allow you to break if one character is missing so you wouldn't need to check the indexes in the end.

Comment: @Filburt: I don't understand what you mean. My check at the end is something like this `boolean ret=true;for(int i=0;i<26 && ret;i++) ret&=seen[i];return ret;`.

Comment: You don't need to do a second scan, just increment a counter when you turn on a bit, i.e. ...{ count+=(!letters[i]); letters[i]++} ... return 26 == count;

Comment: @MAK Well if you discover that there's no "b" in your input string it's a) pointless to try 24 more characters and b) pointless to scan your array at the end. In that case you would want your function return false immediately.

Answer (score 1):

An array of 26 booleans is enough, each entry representing on of the alphabet letters. You can set the entry to true when the letter is found.

Answer (score 1):

I'd go for a sieve algorithm on the 26 letters. Just my $.02.

Edit: An array of 26 values that represent the 26 letters of the alphabet. Then scan the string, checking each letter as you encounter it. At the end, check if the 26 letters have been checked.

Answer (score 1):

```
    public class Pangram {
    public static boolean isPangram(String test){
        for (char a = 'A'; a <= 'Z'; a++)
            if ((test.indexOf(a) < 0) && (test.indexOf((char)(a + 32)) < 0))
                return false;
        return true;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println(isPangram("the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"));//true
        System.out.println(isPangram("the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog"));//false, no s
        System.out.println(isPangram("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"));//true
        System.out.println(isPangram("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQSTUVWXYZ"));//false, no r
        System.out.println(isPangram("ABCDEFGHIJKL.NOPQRSTUVWXYZ"));//false, no m
        System.out.println(isPangram("ABC.D.E.FGHI*J/KL-M+NO*PQ R\nSTUVWXYZ"));//true
        System.out.println(isPangram(""));//false
        System.out.println(isPangram("Pack my box with five dozen liquor jugs."));//true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one out it's easy and simple to understand

```
import java.util.*;

public class Pnagram{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        String Str=sc.nextLine();
        Set<Character> set = new HashSet<Character>();

        for(char c:Str.toUpperCase().toCharArray()){
            if(Character.isLetter(c))
            set.add(c);
        }
        if(set.size()==26)
            System.out.println("pnagram");
        else
            System.out.println("not pnagram");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate over your string for each letter of the alphabet you want to check. When you find the letter you are looking for, continue with the next. If you don’t, abort. Here is some pseudo-code:

```
found = true;
for (letter in letters) {
    if (!string.contains(letter)) {
        found = false;
        break;
    }
}
```

This way you do not need to store the information for each letter but you have to search the string again and again for each letter. What you end up using will depend on your requirements: should it be fast? Should it use little memory? Your decision. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String A ="asdfsdafasdf";
    String B ="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    String C ="ASDFGFHWER";
    String result = "NO";

    String letters[] = {A,B,C};
    int length = letters.length;

    for(int j=0; j< length; j++){
        String letter = letters[j].toLowerCase();
        int letterLength = letter.length();
        for(char i='a'; i<'z'+1; i++){
            if(letter.contains (""+i)){
                result ="YES";
            } else{
                result = "NO";
            }
        }
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not an optimal solution, yet easy to understand :) !

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Solution {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String s = in.nextLine().toUpperCase();
    char[] sarray = s.toCharArray();
    char[] alphabets = {'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z'};
    Set<Character> set = new HashSet<Character>();
    for(int i=0;i<sarray.length;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<alphabets.length;j++){
            if(sarray[i] == alphabets[j]){
                set.add(sarray[i]);
                break;
            }
            continue;
        }
    }
    if(set.size() == 26){
        System.out.println("pangram");
    }else{
        System.out.println("not pangram");
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Explanation

First I will convert all string chars to uppercase.

in ASCII Table you can find uppercase chars ranges, i.e. between 65 to 90

> A == 65 and Z == 90

So, `for` loop should start from 65 and end on 90.

Check if the string contains current ASCII char.

I am converting integer to char and put "" to be string

```
if !text.contains((char)i + "") == true
```

This implies that if the string does not have the current char to `i`, I will `return false`.

You can make it even better by using `char i` in loop

```
static boolean isPangram(String text) {
    //change all chars to upper case
    text = text.toUpperCase();
    //Loop from A to Z
    for(int i = 65 ; i < 91 ; i++){
        //if text not contains return false
        if(!text.contains((char)i + "")){   
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Please add an Explanation

Answer (score 0):

Not a optimal solution but it works.

```
String a= new String("the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog");
        int n=a.length();
        int[] b= new int[123];
        char x;
        boolean flag=true;
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)    
    {

        if(a.charAt(i)==' ')
            continue;
        x=Character.toLowerCase(a.charAt(i));
        b[(int)x]++;

    }
    for(int i=97;i<123;i++)
    {
        if(b[i]==0) 
            {
                flag=false;
                break;
            }
    }
    if(!flag)
        System.out.print("No");
        else
        System.out.print("yes");
```

Answer (score 0):

Just another solution, using Array instead of Set

```
public static boolean isPanagram(String input) {
    if(input == null || input.trim().equals(""))
        return false;

    boolean[] chars = new boolean[26];
    int count = 0;
    for(char c : input.toLowerCase().toCharArray()) {
        if(Character.isAlphabetic(c)) {
            int val = (int) c - 'a';
            if(val >= 0 || val <= 26) {
                if(!chars[val]) {
                    count++;
                    chars[val] = true;
                }
            }
            // checking if all 26 alphabets are set, for every new alphabet found. 
            // so can return true immediately instead of processing entire string
            if(count==26)
                return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this method, is very simple and works fast

```
public static String checkSentence(String mySentence)
{
    String result = "";
    char[] alphabet = {'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'};

    String missingLetters = "";
    int countMissLetters = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < alphabet.length; i++)
    {
        if (!mySentence.toLowerCase().contains(String.valueOf(alphabet[i]).toLowerCase()))
            {
                missingLetters = missingLetters + String.valueOf(alphabet[i]) + " ";
                countMissLetters++;
            }
    }

    result = "Letters who are missing: " + missingLetters + "Counted: " + countMissLetters;
    return result;
}
```

with this exemple

```
System.out.println(checkSentence("Your own sentence to test."));
System.out.println(checkSentence("abcdefghijklmnoprstuvwxyz"));
```

will return this results

```
Letters who are missing: a b d f g h i j k l m p q v x z Counted: 16
Letters who are missing: q Counted: 1
```