# Code to tell whether a string is a Pangram or not?

Tags: java, string, java.util.scanner, pangram

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;


public class Solution {

    public static final int n = 26; 

    public int check(String arr) {
        if (arr.length() < n) {
           return -1;
        }
        for (char c = 'A'; c <= 'Z'; c++) {
            if ((arr.indexOf(c) < 0) && (arr.indexOf((char)(c + 32)) < 0)) {
               return -1;
            }
        }
        return 1;
    }  
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner s1 = new Scanner(System.in);
    String s = s1.next();
    Solution obj = new Solution();

    int d = obj.check(s);

    if (d == -1) {
        System.out.print("not pangram");
    } else {
        System.out.print("pangram");
    }
}
```

If the string entered is:
*We promptly judged antique ivory buckles for the next prize*

It will give the **wrong** output:
**not pangram**.

I'm not able to find out what wrong with the code.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Let debug your code, why check method return -1? You returned -1 on multiple places. Than you will get your answer.

Comment: the first return is when the length of my string is less than 26 characters .. thus it cannot be a pangram 
if the length is more then it goes on and check if all the alphabets are present in the string or not ..
if not it return -1

in the end if the runs fine through the string it returns 1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if string has all the letters of the alphabet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3734511/check-if-string-has-all-the-letters-of-the-alphabet)

Comment: @bummi: not really. The proposed duplicate asks for any algorithm; OP has one but it contains errors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that *whitespace* is a separator for `Scanner.next()`. So when you input `We promptly judged antique ivory buckles for the next prize`, `s` will point just to the string `We`. When you call `obj.check(s)` on `We` it will return `-1`.

To verify that this is the case, you can print `s` and check its value. You can also do:

```
String s = "We promptly judged antique ivory buckles for the next prize";
```

Call `obj.check(s)` and see that it will return the correct answer.

To fix it you should call `Scanner.nextLine()` instead of `Scanner.next()`:

```
String s = s1.nextLine();
```

Answer (score 6):

```
May be program by using set will make solution easier ..:)


import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class Pangram {

public static void main(String args[]) {

    try {
        final String str;
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        str = br.readLine().toLowerCase().replaceAll(" ", "");

        char[] chars = str.toCharArray();
        final Set set = new HashSet();

        for(char c: chars){
            set.add(c);
        }

        System.out.println(set.size());
        if(set.size() == 26)
           System.out.println("pangram");
        else
            System.out.println("not pangram");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Possibly a better solution, but OP is asking what is wrong with his own code - not for a better solution.

Answer (score 6):

Another version:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String sentence = scan.nextLine();
        sentence = sentence.toUpperCase();
        sentence = sentence.replaceAll("[^A-Z]", "");

        char[] chars = sentence.toCharArray();

        Set<Character> set = new HashSet<Character>();

        for( int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++ ) set.add(chars[i]);

        System.out.println(set.size() == 26 ? "pangram" : "not pangram");

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another Similar Solution for your problem.

```
 public class PangramExample {  

      public static void main(String[] args) {  
           String s = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";  
           System.out.println("Is given String Pangram ? : "  
                     + isPangramString(s.toLowerCase()));  
      }  
      private static boolean isPangramString(String s) {  
           if (s.length() < 26)  
                return false;  
           else {  
                for (char ch = 'a'; ch <= 'z'; ch++) {  
                     if (s.indexOf(ch) < 0) {  
                          return false;  
                     }  
                }  
           }  
           return true;  
      }  
 }
```

for reference , refer this link http://techno-terminal.blogspot.in/2015/11/java-program-to-check-if-given-string.html

Comment: OP is not looking for alternative solutions.

Answer (score 1):

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Solution {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
   String input = scanner.nextLine(); 
    System.out.println(isPangram(input) ? "pangram" : "not pangram"); 
}

static boolean isPangram(String input) {
    boolean isPangram = false;

    if(input == null || input.length() < 26) {
        return isPangram;
    }

    input = input.toLowerCase();
    char [] charArray = input.toCharArray();
    Set<Character> charSet = new HashSet<>();
    for(char c : charArray) {
        if(Character.isLetter(c) && (!Character.isWhitespace(c))) {
            charSet.add(c);
        }
    }
    if (charSet.size() == 26) {
        isPangram = true;
    }
    return isPangram;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Pangrams {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String s = sc.nextLine();
        int[] a = new int[26];
        int count =0;
        for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++){
            if(s.charAt(i)>=65 && s.charAt(i)<=90){
                if(a[s.charAt(i)-65]==0)
                    count++;
                a[s.charAt(i)-65]++;
            }
            else if(s.charAt(i)>=97 && s.charAt(i)<=122){
                if(a[s.charAt(i)-97]==0)
                    count++;
                a[s.charAt(i)-97]++;
            }
        }
        if(count==26)
            System.out.println("pangram");
        else
            System.out.println("not pangram");
    }

}
```

Comment: Instead of simply posting code, please include an explanation along with your answer. Please see (How to Answer)[http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer].

Comment: Instead of simply posting code, please include an explanation along with your answer. Kindly read [How to Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This should fix it:

```
import java.io.*;        
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Solution {

        public static boolean isPangram(String test){
            for (char a = 'A'; a <= 'Z'; a++)
                if ((test.indexOf(a) < 0) && (test.indexOf((char)(a + 32)) < 0))
                    return false;
            return true;
        }

        public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException {
            /* Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT. Your class should be named Solution. */
           BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            String test=br.readLine();
            if(isPangram(test.toUpperCase())){

                System.out.println("pangram");

            }if(isPangram(test.toUpperCase())==false){

                System.out.println("not pangram");

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please describe your fixes. OP explicitly asks what is wrong with his code.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String s;
        char f;
         Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        s = in.nextLine();

        char[] charArray = s.toLowerCase().toCharArray();
        final Set set = new HashSet();

        for (char a : charArray) {
            if ((int) a >= 97 && (int) a <= 122) {
                f = a;
                set.add(f);
            }

        }
        if (set.size() == 26){
            System.out.println("pangram");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("not pangram");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please describe how this fixes the OP's code. As far as I can tell, it's a totally independent solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Pangram {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    int count=0;//Initialize counter to zero
    char[] arr = new char[26];//Character array of 26 size as there are 26 alphabets
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String s = sc.nextLine();

    for(int i= 0; i<s.length();i++)
    {
        if(s.charAt(i)>=65 && s.charAt(i)<=90)//Ascii value of A to Z(caps)
        {
            if(arr[s.charAt(i)-65]==0)
            {
                count++;
                arr[s.charAt(i)-65]=1;
            }   
        }

        if(s.charAt(i)>=97 && s.charAt(i)<=122)//Ascii value of a to z
        {
            if(arr[s.charAt(i)-97]==0)
            {
                count++;
                arr[s.charAt(i)-97]=1;
            }

        }
    }

    System.out.println(count);

    if(count==26)
    {
        System.out.println("Pangram");
    }
    else
        System.out.println("not Pangram");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach of doing this

```
public boolean isPanGram(String arg)
{
    String temp = arg.toLowerCase().replaceAll(" ", "");

    String str = String.valueOf(temp.toCharArray());
    String[] array = str.split("");
    Set<String> tempSet = new TreeSet(Arrays.asList(array));
    if(tempSet.size()==26)
    {
        List loopList = new ArrayList();
        loopList.addAll(tempSet);
        if(loopList.get(0).equals("a") && loopList.get(25).equals("z"))
            return true;
    }

return false;   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it

```
static String pangrams(String s) {

    String result="";
    String ls = s.toLowerCase();
    HashSet<Character> ts=new HashSet<Character>(); 
    for(int i=0;i<ls.length();i++){
        if(ls.charAt(i)!=' '){
            ts.add(ls.charAt(i));
        }
    }
    if(ts.size()==26){
        result="pangram";
    }
    else{
        result="not pangram";
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another simple program using HashSet collection.

```
import java.util.HashSet;

public class Panagram {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        pangrams("qmExzBIJmdELxyOFWv LOCmefk TwPhargKSPEqSxzveiun");
    }

    static String pangrams(String s) {

        String inputString = s.toLowerCase();

        HashSet<String> toRemoveDuplicates = new HashSet<String>();
        for (String eachAlphabet : inputString.split("")) {
            toRemoveDuplicates.add(eachAlphabet);
        }

        // Total alphabets are 26 + one space, so 27.
        if (toRemoveDuplicates.size() == 27) 
            return "panagram";
         else 
            return "not panagram";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a different approach, but easy to understand and write.
First remove all punctuation/whitespace, then drop all duplicated letters.
Finally make sure the modified string has exactly 26 letters.

```
public class Pangrams {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog" //any text
                   .replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]+", "") //remove all punctuation and whitespace

        if (s.length() < 1 || s.length() > 100)
            System.exit(0);

        boolean isPangram = false;
        char ch;
        String modifiedStr = "";

        //remove all duplicate letters
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            ch = s.charAt(i);
            if (ch != ' ') {
                modifiedStr += ch;
                s = s.replace(ch, ' ');
            }
        }

        //check whether it has exactly 26 letters
        if (modifiedStr.length() == 26) {
            isPangram = true;
            System.out.println("I am a pangram");
        }
        else System.out.println("I am not a pangram");

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

plain Java for loop to detect if string is Pangram:

```
for (char c = 'a'; c <= 'z'; c++)
if (str.toLowerCase().indexOf(c)== -1)
    return false;
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's a more straight forward approach. It also takes into consideration the repetition of letters, numbers of spaces, tabs and all. You can actually work out with real time sentences. And also if you are a newbie, you won't find this code hard to understand (or i hope so) :)

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Solution{

    static boolean check(String str){

        str=str.toUpperCase();
        int count=0;
        for(char c='A';c<='Z';c++){
            if( (str.indexOf(c)>=0) )
                count++;
        }
        if(count ==26)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){

        Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);
        String s=scan.nextLine();
        if(check(s))
            System.out.println("pangram");
        else
            System.out.println("not pangram");

    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public class Panagram 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("enter string ");
        String s = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("given string is :"+"\n" +s);
        String st=removeSpace(s);

       int d = check(st);
        if(d == -1)
            System.out.print(s+"\n" + "is not pangram");
        else
             System.out.print(s+"\n" +"is a pangram");

    }
    public static String removeSpace(String s) 
    {
        char ch[]=s.toCharArray();
        String nstr="";
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) 
        {
            if (ch[i]!=' ') 
            {
                nstr=nstr + ch[i];
            }
        }

   return nstr;
    }

    public  static int check(String st)
    {

         int n = 26; 

        if(s.length() < n){
           return -1;   }

        for(char i = 'A'; i <= 'Z' ; i++){
            if((st.indexOf(i) < 0) && (st.indexOf((char)(i + 32)) < 0))
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you [earn](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/146472/169503) sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). If you have a related but different question, [ask a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) referencing this one if it will help provide context.